# How to use WebDriver Wait in IE?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have Home Page, from the if I click Login, it will be navigated to another page (there i have to enter login credentials to login the account.

Without the below piece of Code, it is perfectly working for Firefox and Chrome.. But IE it is not working.. I assumed to add wait so that IE problem will resolve..

```
WebDriverWait Test_Wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
 WebElement click=Test_Wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementIfVisible("login_xpath"));
```

I have added this code.. But I am getting error to change elementIfVisible to elementClickable.. If i change to elementClickable. Again it is giving error to change elementIfVisible.. How to resolve this??

```
package com.test.testCase;

import java.io.File;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import com.test.utitlity.clickEvent;
import com.test.utitlity.globalVariables;
import com.test.utitlity.switchWindow;

public class driverManager extends globalVariables{
    public static void driverManager(){
       browser="ie";
       if(browser.equals("ie")){    
       File file = new File("./IEDriverServer.exe");        
       System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getPath());
       driver= new InternetExplorerDriver();
       }
      else if (browser.equals("firefox"))
       {
           driver=new FirefoxDriver();
       }
       else if (browser.equals("chrome"))
       {
           File file= new File("./chromedriver.exe");
           System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getPath());
           System.out.println(file.getPath());
           driver=new ChromeDriver();
       }
       driver.get("http://www.xxxx.in");
       clickEvent.clickAt("login_xpath");
       WebDriverWait Test_Wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
       WebElement click=Test_Wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementIfVisible("login_xpath"));
       switchWindow.swindow("TST.");        

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code as I can see, you are using it incorrectly. **First, you have to wait for the element to be visible and then you have to click on it but you are using it the other way around, and hence it is not able to find the login button as it has been clicked and you are in the new page already.**

Please use the wait like this. This will work in all browsers (IE, always a hindrance, but it will work nevertheless):

```
    try{
        WebDriverWait Test_Wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
        WebElement click=Test_Wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("login_xpath")));
        clickEvent.clickAt("login_xpath");
    }catch(Throwable e){
        System.err.println("The login element is not found");
    }
```